# SQL Server Named Pipes Provider Error BUT only with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, named-pipes

I have a SQL Server instance that is throwing the "Named Pipes Provider" error, code 40. I know that this is a relatively common error on new installs and there's a convoluted process to fix it. However, the odd part of this error for me is that (1) it only happens intermittently and (2) it only happens with my ASP.NET application. I have other apps that are accessing this server just fine without any errors.

I came across a vague reference to this error happening when your connection string is part of the ASPX code (as opposed to the web.config) and that doesn't make sense but it's the only option I could come up with. Anyone else seen this?

Comment: how are you referencing your sql server? By name or ip?  You might want to try alternating both.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a security context issue? How is the asp.net application accessing the sql server? Integrated windows security or sql security? If the earlier check that the identity of the application (asp.net process) which is defined by the Application Pool identity has login rights on the DB.

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/03/31/named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server.aspx :

Summary, give checklist:

1. Is your target server started?
2. Is your target server listening on NP? Which Pipe?
3. Has your client enabled NP? Use the same pipe to connect as Server?
4. Are you making local connection? If so, what is the instance, default or remote?
5. Did you put correct instance name in the connection string? Remember, Sqlexpress is a named instance.
6. Did you enable remote connection? Firewall? IPSec? "File and Printer Sharing" opened? Can access server?
7. Can you make basic connection by using  or \? Use sqlcmd or osql.